# How to form a for loop which performs descending order in Scilab

Tags: for-loop, scilab

I was trying to perform a descend loop in Scilab 
like:

```
for i=7: 1 
    disp(i);
end
```

But apparently it didn't work and there are no errors too.

Is this possible? And if yes, how to do it?

Comment: was the answer usefull?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, yes It did work thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Syntax

As the [for-loop documentation](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.2/en_US/for.html) states, the for loop's syntax is:

```
for variable=expression do instruction, ,instruction,end
```

If `expression` is a matrix or a row vector, `variable` takes as values the values of each column of the matrix.

### Your example

Your for-loop uses 7:1 as `expression`, what will result in a valid but empty vector:

```
-->7:1
 ans  =

     []
```

The for-loop then takes each value in the vector and then finishes, but since your vector is empty it finishes directly. So it is valid syntax.

### Working example

The documentation gives the following example of a working decreasing loop:

```
for j=4:-1:1
   disp(j);
end // decreasing loop
```